# Which is best way to grep on exec from find command?

Tags: bash, grep, find, exec

I'm just curious which of these statements would be most resource intensive.

I expect the criteria at times to be 1000s of files, and want to make sure I implement the "safest" execution. Files themselves will be relatively small, but the amount of files might be substantially large.

The two alternatives:

```
sudo find /home/users -name '*.sh' -type f -exec grep -n 'rm.*tmp.*7z$' {} \+
sudo find /home/users -name '*.sh' -type f -exec grep -Hn 'rm.*tmp.*7z$' {} \;
```

As you can see the only difference is whether I should use the + or the ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is going to run `grep` fewer times than the second, which will launch one instance per file. `grep`'s startup time is pretty fast, so it might not be much of a visible improvement, but the first one will be more efficient, the second one more resource intensive.

(You'll want to add `-H` to the first `grep`'s options too, just in case it gets run with a single filename argument at some point.)